# sitemapdatasource does not call OnDataBinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, sitemapprovider

I would like to filter entries from `web.sitemap` using `OnDataBinding` event, but it does not execute. I would like to have functionality, which allows me to verify whether user's role have access to particular function.

I created table with list of functions and linking table to build priviledges. I am going to allow administrator to add new roles and give them set of functions which are allowed rather than using IsInRole which does not seem flexible enough to my needs.

So, I added the following:

```
<asp:sitemapdatasource ID="SiteMapMenuSrc" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" OnDataBinding="MainMenu_DataBinding" SiteMapProvider="SiteMap1"></asp:sitemapdatasource>
```

Where SiteMap is web.config entry:

```
<add name="SiteMap1" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap"/>
```

It seems, that `MainMenu_DataBinding` is not called. I have not found any suitable explanation. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `SiteMapDatasource` is just a **data source control** it does nothing on its own

You actually have to use it, for example:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" DataSourceID="SiteMapMenuSrc" runat="server" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="Table" 
        StaticSubMenuIndent="16px">
        <StaticSelectedStyle Font-Bold="True" />
    </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after I added this Menu I still can not get OnDataBinding from sitemapdatasource. Shall I use Menu events for that?

Comment: I just made an experiment and you are right, but if you call in your page: `this.DataBind();` in your `Page_Load` event, your event gets fired. However the usual way to handle this is to handle the events of the data bound control not the events from the data source control.